# Get daily count of users by id returning error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I am trying to get daily count of unique users from a SQL Server table.

An example of how the table would look like:

```
user_id start_timestamp     activity
111     08/25/2020 13:23    aaaa
111     08/25/2020 14:24    bbbb
222     08/25/2020 14:26    cccc
222     08/25/2020 14:28    dddd
333     08/25/2020 14:31    eeee
```

An example of the result table I am looking for:

```
user_id start_date  count
111     08/25/2020  2
222     08/25/2020  2
333     08/25/2020  1
```

This is what I have tried. '

```
SELECT 
    [user_id],  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,[start_timestamp], 23) as [start_date]
    COUNT([user_id]) AS [user_count]
  FROM [dbo].[user_activity]
  GROUP BY [user_id],[start_date]
  ORDER BY [start_date]
```

I had to convert the date from timestamp to just dates for the group by but I keep getting an error message:

> Invalid column name 'start_date'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single select statement you aren't able to use the alias setup by the select clause in the group by clause.

```
SELECT 
    [user_id],  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,[start_timestamp], 23) as [start_date] --<< established here
    COUNT([user_id]) AS [user_count]
FROM [dbo].[user_activity]
GROUP BY [user_id],[start_date] --<< illegal reuse of alias here
ORDER BY [start_date]
```

You can avoid this by simply repeating the information before the alias, like this

```
SELECT 
    [user_id],  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,[start_timestamp], 23) as [start_date] --<< established here
    COUNT([user_id]) AS [user_count]
FROM [dbo].[user_activity]
GROUP BY [user_id],CONVERT(VARCHAR,[start_timestamp], 23) --<< no alias here
ORDER BY [start_date]
```

I would prefer to see you cast the timestamp to a date instead of converting to a string.

```
SELECT 
    [user_id],  
    cast([start_timestamp] as date) as [start_date] --<< alias established here
    COUNT([user_id]) AS [user_count]
FROM [dbo].[user_activity]
GROUP BY [user_id],cast([start_timestamp] as date)
ORDER BY [start_date]
```

Comment: Do not use `VARCHAR` without a length in SQL Server.  The default length varies by context and this is just a really bad habit that will lead to coding errors at some part.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the converted date column to grıup by section.

```
SELECT 
    [user_id],  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,[start_timestamp], 23) as [start_date]
    COUNT([user_id]) AS [user_count]
  FROM [dbo].[user_activity]
  GROUP BY [user_id],CONVERT(VARCHAR,[start_timestamp], 23)
  ORDER BY [start_date]
```

Answer (score 0):

The column alias `[start_date]` is created *after* the `GROUP BY` is evaluated.

Instead use a *derived table* (the subquery) to first get the `[start_date]`, and then `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
    [user_id],  
    [start_date]
    COUNT([user_id]) AS [user_count]
FROM
(
  SELECT 
      [user_id],
      CONVERT(VARCHAR,[start_timestamp], 23) as [start_date]
  FROM [dbo].[user_activity]
) dt
GROUP BY [user_id], [start_date]
ORDER BY [start_date]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should not convert to `varchar` to get a date without a time. Instead convert to `date`.**

As mentioned by others, you cannot reuse a `select` alias in the `group by`. You can repeat the same `convert` again, but a better way is to place it into a `cross apply`, this allows you to reuse it later.

You should also use proper table aliasing.

```sql
SELECT 
    u.user_id,  
    v.start_date
    COUNT(user_id) AS user_count
  FROM dbo.user_activity u
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES( CAST(u.start_timestamp AS date) ) v(start_date)
  GROUP BY u.user_id, v.start_date
  ORDER BY v.start_date
```